# How to change font size in VB.net

Tags: .net, email

I want to below script to send an email to lotus notes, but I find that in lotus notes, the font size of body message is a little bigger, so I want to change its font size to a small one, but due to string body in below function is a variable, I don't know how to change its font size, so could anyone here can help me ? thanks in advance

```
    Public Shared Sub SendMail(ByVal from As String, ByVal towhere As String, ByVal subject As String, ByVal body As String)
    Dim mailservername As String
    mailservername = "POSTMASTER@mailserver.com"

    Dim Message As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from, towhere, subject, body)

    Dim mailClient As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient()
    mailClient.Host = mailservername
    mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = True
    mailClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis
    mailClient.Send(Message)
    End Sub

   the body message is such as body = str1 + " " + str2 + " " + str3
   str1 and str2 are constant strings, but str3 are variable, what I want to change is str3's font size
```

Answer (score 1):

The mail body can be in different formats. What your using above is pain text format (content type is text/plain). You can use html format (text/html) along with (or instead of) text format, then in html, you can style your mail richly using CSS styles or html tags. See this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150716/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/080206-1.aspx) that introduce how to send an html mail.

**Edit**: Edited to put code fragment (in comment, it becomes messy)

```
body = "<span style=""font-size:10pt;"">" + str1 + " " + str2 + "</span><span style=""font-size:12pt;"">" + str3 + "</span>"
mailClient.Body = body
mailClient.IsBodyHtml = True
```

Comment: the body message is such as 
body = str1 + " " + str2 + " " + str3
str1 and str2 are constant strings, but str3 are variable, what I want to change is str3's font size

Comment: If your using html body then you can put str3 in span tag and specify font size there. For example,
body = "<span style=""font-size:10pt;"">" + str1 + " " + str2 + "</span><span style=""font-size:12pt;"">" + str3 + "</span>"